# How do I resolve ORA-01017 error on Oracle SQL Developer 23.1 when the username and password are correct?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-01017

How do I resolve ORA-01017 error on Oracle SQL Developer 23.1 when the username and password are correct?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmCGK.png)

I just downloaded Oracle 23.1 and tried connecting a database file after GRANT CONNECT script

CREATE USER intro_user IDENTIFIED BY mypassword;

GRANT CONNECT TO intro_user;

GRANT CREATE SESSION, GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO intro_user;

GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO intro_user;

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO intro_user

Please assist

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are connecting to the RIGHT database.

Don't use SID in your connection properties, use the SERVICE name. And I'm guessing you are using XE18 where your user exists in a PDB, and connecting to SID:XE will NOT put you in the PDB where you want to do work.